# queryForRowSet doesn't return results with null in optional date parameter

Tags: java, oracle, jdbctemplate, optional-parameters

I added optional date parameters to several Oracle SQL/Code which worked except from specific SQL used in combination with `queryForRowSet`

My SQL with optional date:

```
SELECT * from I where  I.MYDATE <= nvl(?, I.MYDATE)
```

Code sending null for optional date:

```
Object[] param= new Object[] {null};
SqlRowSet result = jdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet(QUERY, param);
```

If I remove parameter SQL return results, but with null it doesn't return results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide information about the type of the null:

```
Object[] param = { null };
int[]    paramType = { java.sql.Types.DATE };

SqlRowSet result = jdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet(QUERY, param, paramType);
```

Or, it should work when the parameter type is explicitly specified this way (as you have only one parameter for the query):

```
java.sql.Date[] param = { null };
SqlRowSet result = jdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet(QUERY, param);
```

Comment: So it converts to other type instead of date?

Comment: It just cannot determine which sql type is expected in the query.